# Parse many csv from external web provider in parallel

Tags: java, csv

I'm trying to process multiple csv at the same time. My code looks like this :

```
public class CSVMain{

private static int count = 3;

public static void main(String[] a){

    ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(300);         
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++) e.execute(new WebRunner("http://some.host.com"));         
    e.shutdown();

}

static class WebRunner implements Runnable{

    private final String url;

    public WebRunner(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            URL MyUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) MyUrl.openConnection();
            conn.connect();

            IOUtils.toByteArray(MyUrl.openStream());

            System.out.println(new DateTime().toString("HH:mm:ss,SSS") + " finish thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - now));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

}

}
```

If I set the static `count` variable to 1, it would complete in 600-700 ms with my connection. When it's 2, I'll get around 1100-1400ms, when 3, it's 1700-1900ms and so on.

The statistics feels sequential, not parallel.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several points that contribute to this.

First, you are measuring the run-time of individual Runnables, not the total run-time for the sequential runs (i.e. you run the `WebRunner` three times, one after the other) versus the concurrent runs (you give them to a thread pool, like you are doing here).

Another important fact is that concurrency doesn't mean that things will execute in parallel. [Concurrency is not parallelism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cN_DpYBzKso) They might, or they might not. Concurrency is also highly non-deterministic. That is, when the threads are allowed to run and for how long they run depends on a lot of things, including the operating system. Depending on the circumstances, they might even end up running sequentially (regardless of the size of your thread pool). And they might even appear to be executing in parallel, but they might do so in a round-robin fashion, without much benefit from concurrency and and with the overhead of switching. There are a lot of subtleties to concurrency. For an in-depth guide, the best resource is [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601).

Also, even if the tasks do run in parallel, there are other restrictions on performance.For ex. you might have limited network bandwidth and when the tasks run in parallel, they might end up competing for that limited resource. The same is true for both computing power and memory.

Another very important thing is that, what you are doing is a naive version of micro benchmarking. In order to get more reliable benchmarking stats, you should probably use something like [The JMH framework](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). Here's a relevant article on the [pitfalls of naive java benchmarking](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-benchmark1/) and an [an article on JMH](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-benchmarking-2266277.html)

The TL;DR; version is: do not try to assign meaning to the performance of concurrent applications without a lot of rigor.

Comment: Thank for the reply. If that's the case, do you know how to identify the bottleneck for this code? Thanks

Comment: You can identify the bottlenecks with the use of benchmarking frameworks (like JMH) and a combination of a lot of trial and error and experimentation. Finding the bottlenecks in code is not an exact science, and there are no set ways of how to do it. Benchmark different parts of the code and see if a discernible pattern emerges. And even if you find patterns, try to be skeptical about them, as, again, it's not an exact science.

Answer (score 0):

[uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial)'s CsvParser reads your input using a separate thread by default. There's no need to read your stream into a byte array before processing the CSV. It's also 3 times faster than commons-csv. Try the following code:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); //many configuration options here, check the tutorial.
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

URL MyUrl = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) MyUrl.openConnection();
conn.connect();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(MyUrl.openStream(), "UTF-8");
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(reader);
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).